# When can we lift transitivity of an action from geometric points to a flat cover?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, schemes

Let $G$ a nice group scheme (say, over $S$), $X$ a smooth $G$-scheme over $S$, that is, $\pi : X \to S$ a smooth, $G$-invariant morphism. Assume that the action is **transitive on algebraically closed fibers**; that is, for any $p : \operatorname{Spec} \overline{k} \to S$, that $G(\overline{k})$ acts transitively on the fibers $\pi^{-1}(p) \subset X(\overline{k})$.

Under what conditions can we determine whether $X \to S$ is **locally connected** by the action of $G$? That is, for $T \to S$ an *arbitrary* scheme and $x,y \in X(T)$, when does there necessarily exist a cover $\{T' \to T\}$ (flat, étale, . . .) and $g \in G(T')$ such that $x|_{T'} = g.y|_{T'}$?

Comment: What are you assuming about $G$ and $S$.  If $G$ is $S$-smooth, then the following is an $S$-morphism between smooth $S$-schemes, $G\times_S X \to X\times_S X$.  Your hypothesis implies all geometric fibers have constant dimension.  Using limit theorems and the local flatness criterion, the morphism is flat.  If you further assume that $S$ has characteristic zero, then the morphism is smooth.

Comment: No assumptions about $S$ (I need to test this for $S$ ranging over a big flat site over a field in positive characteristic), but $G$ is $S$-smooth, yes (it comes from a smooth $k$-group). How do these geometric properties of the graph of the action map relate to this sheafy local connectedness condition?

Comment: With no hypotheses on $S$, you do at least get flatness.  Given two $S$-morphisms to $X$, this gives an $S$-morphism to $X\times_S X$.  Take the base change with the morphism above to get a flat cover of $T$ that admits a projection to $G$.

Comment: By the way, there are examples showing that you cannot improve "flat" to "smooth" in characteristic $p>0$.  Let $G$ and $X$ both equal $\mathbb{G}_m$, and let the action $G\times X \to X$ send $(s,t)$ to $s^pt$.  Let $T$ be $X$.  Let the first morphism be the identity morphism on $X$, and let the second morphism be the constant morphism with image $1\in X$.